# Optimizing more than one function simultaneous in fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization, simultaneous

I have more than one function to optimiz and want to run fmincon simultaneous for them. For example, assume that there are 4 different functions A, B, C and D. Normally, it optimize sequentially. I mean it first optimize A, then B, then C and D.

[image]

I want to put all A, B, C and D in optimization process and obtain the results step by step. I mean first 1st iteration for A,B, c and D, then 2nd, then 3rd....

Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: I have too many cases and I have to eliminate some of them. That's the reason.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to make fmincon do what you're asking; I think you'll have to write your own optimization function if you want to do this.

Comment: Another question, are there any possibility to stop the iteration in fmincon? For example, I computed A and B and I noticed the values in B are higher than A and I want to stop at 3rd iteration. Are there any possibilities to do that?

Comment: you can pass more detailed options to fmincon. See here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimoptions.html

You can set MaxIter option.